# X pattern with nested condition in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int column, row, n(5);
    int middle = (n+1)/2;

    for(column = 1; column <= n; column++){
        for(row = 1; row <= n; row++){
            if((n % 2) == 1){
                if(column == middle && row == middle)
                    cout << "o";
            } else if(column == row){
                cout << "\\";
            } else if(row == (n-column+1)){
                cout << "/";
            } else{
                cout << " "; }
        } cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

basically i want to create an X pattern. It's pretty simple, if the n value is odd then it'd print the character "o" in the middle of the pattern. But if n value is even, then don't print the character "o". It works perfectly with even number, say n = 6. Then the code above generates,

```
\    /
 \  /
  \/
  /\
 /  \
/    \
```

But if the n value is odd, then it only printed a bunch of spaces with no pattern at all. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code with a debugger before posting the question here? With a good debugger, you can pause the execution of your code and inspect values of the variabes on every single line

Comment: `if((n % 2) == 1){...}else{...}` the else part would never hit for some `n`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

It is because you always hit the `if((n % 2) == 1)` block and print nothing.

You need to change it to `if(column == middle && row == middle && (n % 2) == 1)`.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int column, row, n(5);
    int middle = (n+1)/2;

    for(column = 1; column <= n; column++){
        for(row = 1; row <= n; row++){
            if(column == middle && row == middle&& (n % 2) == 1)
            {
                    cout << "o";
            } else if(column == row){
                cout << "\\";
            } else if(row == (n-column+1)){
                cout << "/";
            } else{
                cout << " "; }
        } cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
\   /
 \ /
  o
 / \
/   \
```

Comment: @Lucifer1002 You had everything to handle the odd number but needed slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            if ((col == row) && (col == n - 1 - row))
            {
                cout << 'o';
            }
            else if (col == row)
            {
                cout << '\\';
            }
            else if (col == n - 1 - row)
            {
                cout << '/';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```